# Transmitted UDP packet?

Tags: java, udp

Am sending a UDP packet in Local host but in never gets to the receiver am trying to debug the application,is there any way to check if a UDP packet was sent in JAVA ?

Answer (score 1):

When you're working with low-level library functions that tie into the operating system, you'll often need an external tool to help you.  In this case, you want a network sniffer that's capable of watching your outgoing packets.  I'd recommend WireShark (http://www.wireshark.org/) but I'll also warn you that you'll need to understand what you're looking for.